# Why shouldn't the magnitude of a practically realizable frequency selective filter be constant for a range of frequencies?

Tags: filters

According to Paley-Wiener theorem, a practically realizable frequency selective filter shouldn't have a constant magnitude for a range of frequencies. Why is this so? How do we prove and understand it?!

> To summarize, causality has very important implications in the design
>   of frequency-selective filters. These are: (a) the frequency response
>   $H(\omega)$ cannot be zero, except at a finite set of points in
>   frequency; (b) the magnitude $|H(\omega)|$ cannot be constant in any
>   finite range of frequencies and the transition from passband to
>   stopband cannot be infinitely sharp [this is a consequence of the
>   Gibbs phenomenon, which results from the truncation of $h(n)$ to
>   achieve causality]; and (c) the real and imaginary parts of
>   $H(\omega)$ are interdependent and are related by the discrete Hilbert
>   transform. As a consequence, the magnitude $|H(\omega)|$ and phase
>   $\Theta(\omega)$ of $H(\omega)$ cannot be chosen arbitrarily.

Point b in the quote. Source: Proakis ch.10 4th edition

Comment: Hi. Rather than constant gain, a constant frequency response (magnitude and phase) should be what you are asking for.

Comment: Sorry I meant magnitude of H(w)

Comment: I didn't understand the difference between gain and magnitude?

Comment: You may want to limit the question to frequency selective filters (as in the quote) which attenuate some frequencies while pass others largely unattenuated. That would exclude all-pass filters.

Comment: @OlliNiemitalo: right, this is probably what the question should be about.

Comment: Thank you so much! I may limit the question to frequency selective filters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that all-pass filters with a perfectly constant magnitude response over the whole frequency range are realizable. A first-order discrete-time all-pass filter has the following transfer function:

$$H(z)=\frac{1-az^{-1}}{a^*-z^{-1}}\tag{1}$$

If $|a|>1$, the system $(1)$ is causal and stable. It is straightforward to show that

$$\left|H\left(e^{j\omega}\right)\right|=1,\qquad\forall\omega\tag{2}$$

i.e., the system's magnitude response is constant.

What is not possible is to have a constant magnitude response over only a part of the possible frequency range $[0,2\pi]$ (or, in continuous time, $(-\infty,\infty)$).

This can be seen as follows. First, design an ideal frequency-selective filter by computing the IDFT of some ideal frequency response (with a constant gain in the pass band(s), and a gain of zero in the stop band(s)). Let's consider discrete-time filters, but the discussion is basically the same for continuous-time filters. Let the resulting ideal impulse response be $h_{id}[n]$. First, we shift that impulse response to the right to have most of its energy at positive indices $n>0$:

$$\tilde{h}_{id}[n]=h_{id}[n-n_0],\qquad n_0>0\tag{3}$$

In order to obtain a causal filter, we need to multiply that shifted impulse response by a sequence $f[n]$ satisfying

$$f[n]=\begin{cases}0,&n<0\\1,&n>n_1\ge 0\end{cases}\tag{4}$$

with some non-negative $n_1$. The values of $f[n]$ between $n=0$ and $n=n_1$ can be chosen arbitrarily, but in practice we would choose them such that $f[n]$ increases monotonically in the interval $[0,n_1]$. The final impulse response of our causal filter is

$$h[n]=\tilde{h}_{id}[n]f[n]=h_{id}[n-n_0]f[n]\tag{5}$$

Note that $h[n]$ is still infinitely long.

In the frequency domain this corresponds to

$$H(e^{j\omega})=\left(H_{id}(e^{j\omega})e^{-jn_0\omega}\right)\star F(e^{j\omega})\tag{6}$$

where $\star$ denotes convolution. This convolution destroys the piecewise constant property of the original frequency response $H_{id}(e^{j\omega})$, and the magnitude of the resulting causal frequency response $H(e^{j\omega})$ is neither piecewise constant, nor does it have infinitely sharp transitions.

Comment: Thank you so much @Matt L. Very satisfying answer. Can u please tell why in practice f(n) should have monotonically increasing values between 0 to n1?

Comment: @TrilokGirishKamagond: That's just a reasonable choice because you want a function that smoothly moves from zero to one, just like a one-sided window function.

Comment: You show that truncating the impulse response of a filter with a magnitude frequency response with a flat segment no longer gives such a filter. But this leaves out what can or cannot be achieved by truncating the impulse response of a filter that does not originally have that flat segment in its magnitude frequency response.

Comment: @OlliNiemitalo: Yes, that's right, the whole answer clearly doesn't prove anything, it's just supposed to make things plausible.

Comment: @Matt L I have a small doubt regarding multiplication of f(n) to hid[n] to get a causal system. I feel hid[n] is already causal as it depends on past values only as long as n0 is large enough. So what can I understand from the multiplication by f(n)? And when n > n0 won't the system become non causal?

Comment: @TrilokGirishKamagond: Shifting alone cannot make $h_{id}[n]$ causal because it extends to $n\rightarrow\pm\infty$. Shifting only makes the final truncation error smaller because after shifting, most of its energy will be at positive values of $n$.

Comment: So values less than n<0 makes the system non causal?

Comment: @Matt L. On what I understand from causality is that signal should depend only on present and past values and not future. Since hid[n] depends only on past values, won't that make it causal ?

Comment: @TrilokGirishKamagond: Why does $h_{id}[n]$ only depend on past values? It is non-zero for negative values of $n$, which makes it non-causal. That's why you need to truncate it (after having shifted it in order not to lose its most important part).

Comment: @Matt L thank you so much. I understood why we have to make the values zero for n<0.